# Where to put settings for an app in microsoft teams

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

In the microsoft teams admin center under "Teams Apps > Manage Apps" (https://admin.teams.microsoft.com/policies/manage-apps) I can allow/block apps and also add my custom apps.

First question:
For every app there is a tab settings:
[image: screenshotadminsettings]
What are these settings for? I could not find any app having something here and also there is not really a documentation on that? What is this tab?

Second question:
Is it somehow possible to add settings for an app which can be configured by the admin? For example it would be helpful if an admin could specify a "licencekey" in the app settings. it would make sense to have this options in the admin dashboard close on the app itself. Is there anything possible here?
What is the best practice to put these kind of settings?

Answer (score 0):

Tabs are Teams-aware webpages embedded in Microsoft Teams. They are simple HTML  tags that point to domains declared in the app manifest and can be added as part of a channel inside a team, group chat, or personal app for an individual user. Please check this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/what-are-tabs) for more info. You can specify the app settings using admin account. Please check these docs [Manage your apps in the Microsoft Teams admin center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/manage-apps) and [Admin settings for apps in Microsoft Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/admin-settings)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm aware that I can manage apps for users, but the question is more if I as a admin have somehow the option to add some configurations for a specific app in the admin center?. And I do not get the link between "Tabs" in an App and the "Settings"-Tab I can see in the admin center? how is that connected?

Comment: Hi @Stefa,could you please check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/manage/windows-admin-center/configure/user-access-control)